# Agreement (after "each person") with 'has/have' in "each person 'has' their own ..."

Tags: singular-they

In a [blog](http://blogs.hbr.org/2014/06/start-ups-have-office-politics-too/) in Harvard Business Review, David Franke writes:

> After all, *each person* has *their* own ego, personal goals, aspirations and agendas; there is always going to be a need for compromise, negotiation, and politicking.

Does the subject agree with the verb here?

Comment: The coupling of 'their' with 'each' here is misleading. I recently used 'Chiari writes in their article ... ' [it wasn't actually a 'Chiari', but you get the point] because I didn't know if this author with the first name Chiari say was male or female. The practice is certainly acceptable with something like 'When an author publishes their work, ...'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The author is using the singular 'their' for the sake of gender neutrality.

Comment: I've lost the link, but it has been recommended on meta that it is better practice not to give 'answers' to questions that already have answers in previous threads.