# Is "Each person should do their own work" really not logical to say?

Tags: grammar, style-manuals

I am taking English Language Studies as my bachelor's. It happened when one of our subjects' professor, Advanced English Grammar professor, said that the sentence "each person should do their own work" is not logical to say because of "their"'s usage -- or it is grammatically wrong based on prescriptive grammar's view. I think I kind of get it, but I am not satisfied nor convinced with her explanation. Can someone justify why or why not it is not logical?
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Each person has their own ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/176982/subject-verb-agreement-with-each/177005#177005) Or this? [Is there a correct gender-neutral singular pronoun ("his" vs. "her" vs. "their")?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-vs-her-vs-their)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth yes, thank you! I actually thought about the usage of 'their' as a gender-neutral pronoun. But my professor showed a picture, perhaps from Google, saying that prescriptive grammar says that it is grammatically wrong which I thought unacceptable if context exists -- well, semantically speaking, 'their' is also singular. But then again, thank you!